# Is it chaos if a Cloud Function in Node.js has at least 185 complexity?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I was trying to create a Cloud Function using Node.js. At first I created 3 files with each different function, but actually it spent almost 30-45 seconds to finish all of them just for authentication and check the device, only. Then, I decided to combine all the files into one function and now it has 185 complexity. It really became faster and it only requires 10-14 seconds.

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const level = require("../../library/level");
const hamsu = require("../../library/useful");
const db = admin.firestore();
const medium = level.medium;

exports.Authentication = functions.runWith(medium).https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (context.app == undefined) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "failed-precondition",
        "The function must be called from an App Check verified app.");
  }
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("failed-precondition", "Unauthorized User is trying to access the App.");
  }
  let code;
  const token = data.token;
  
 });
```

So, what I wanna ask is does having complexity up to 185 really cause the Server into overload, or not?
Thank you for any tips and tricks. Sorry, I am a newbie.

Comment: This is *cognive* complexity, not "how complex is this code to execute". And yes, most times cognitive complexity above 10-15-ish is too much. Depends on how CC is actually calculated and also depends on the context where the code is. However, 185 seems a lot for a reasonable to maintain code.

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you for answering. So I really do need to refactor it. In other words, I have to simplify it.

Comment: "*it has 185 complexity*" - what does that mean?

Comment: Please visit this url to know what it is like to have 185 complexity: 
https://pasteboard.co/l4Z7GyHvwSMk.png

Comment: Just a sanity check, you do know that you can typically have sub-functions called from your main one? I. E. You have a function that serves as entry point for the cloud, but you can also have other js functions that are not entry points,  but are used just for code organization.

Comment: Actually, I have made 3 sub function which I can call inside the cloud function. And it still has 185 complexity. If I didn't make it, probably it will be 300.

Comment: Think and code like a caveman.

Comment: Okay, I have refactored it into 8 functions and one Cloud Function. Now it has only 11 Cognitive Complexity. Thank you, guys. You can view it on this image link
https://pasteboard.co/oZWb1kYrZSBy.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

185 is very high for cognitive complexity, and would be inadvisable in a situation where:

- Other people need to understand and maintain your code
- You are likely to have memory fade on how the function works
- There is code in that function that is / needs to be duplicated elsewhere

Best practice, generally speaking, is to maintain low cognitive complexity code with as few to non instances of code repetition where possible.

An aside: I hope you enjoy the refactoring process! Some IDEs will offer a refactoring tool built into them which can automate the process somewhat.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I am a newbie. This is a much harder way I think, compared to Flutter. I am gonna learn refactoring it.

Comment: We never stop learning, good on you for making the effort to improve your code! Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I have refactored it into 8 functions and only one Cloud Function. Now it has only 11 Cognitive Complexity. Thank you so much. You can view it on this image [link] (https://pasteboard.co/oZWb1kYrZSBy.png)